# dropping a row in pandas with dates indexes, python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop the last row in a `dataframe` created by pandas in python and seem to be having trouble.

```
index = DateRange('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = DataFrame(randn(8, 3), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I tried the drop method like this:

```
df.drop([shape(df)[0]-1], axis = 0)
```

but it keeps saying label not contained in the axis.

I also tried to drop by index name and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df.ix[:-1]
```

returns the original DataFrame with the last row removed.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew it was something simple but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Bizarrely this didn't seem to work for me (returned empty data frame).  This did though:  df.ix[:len(df)-2]

Comment: @Carl I think the reason why len(df)-2 worked for you is because you probably have an integer index  from zero to len(df), hence you specified your index value.

Answer (score 11):

Referencing the DataFrame directly to retrieve all but the last index worked for me.

```
df[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! `df.ix[:-1]` seems to give me an empty DataFrame. But your solution worked.

Comment: Same here, thanks. Got an empty DataFrame with @eumiro's answer.